# Check if the user is from california

Tags: java, android, location, ccpa

I want to check if the user of my android app is from California so that my app complies with CCPA.
For GDPR i can do that by using this URL
https://adservice.google.com/getconfig/pubvendors
I do not want to get the user location after adding the location permission to my app as that is out of the context or scope of my app
I tried looking for solutions on stackoverflow but they are not reliable and some of them are paid.

Comment: From my understanding, CCPA applies if the user is a CA **resident**.  The owner of a phone that happens to be currently located in CA is not necessarily a CA resident.  Conversely, the owner of  phone that happens to be currently located outside of CA might actually be a CA resident.  So you might want to ask for the user's residence state.  Or, since some other states usually/eventually follow CA's lead, just make it CCPA compliant for all users.

Comment: @AndrewS This will add friction to my app and if user select their state as California they can easily opt out of behavioural targeting

Comment: is there any solution?